# AND statement in "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have ListBox in Access form and trying to filter it using TextBox entry. My ListBox consist of 6 columns and I need to filter it by 2 conditions:

- I need to find all entries containing entered text in any of first 5
  columns
- AND in 6th column containing specific text.

Filter more or less works, I get filtered result by my entry, but problem that my code seems to ignore `AND` statement and shows all results despite 6th column not containing specific text. What I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
Sub PaieskaTb_Change()

Dim strSource As String, strSearch As String
strSearch = Replace(PaieskaTb.Text, "'", "''") 'needed to avoid errors if entry contains apostrophes

    strSource = "SELECT [ID], [VP_veiklioji], [VP_invented_Name], [Pareisk_pav], [Par_gavimo_data], [Statusas] " _
        & "FROM qryNewSys_srch " _
        & "WHERE [ID] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
        & "Or [VP_veiklioji] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
        & "Or [VP_invented_Name] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
        & "Or [Pareisk_pav] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
        & "Or [Par_gavimo_data] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
        & "And [Statusas] = 'Ongoing' " _ 'this line ignored, tried different apostrophes but no result
        & "ORDER BY [ID] DESC"


Me.Paraisku_sarasas.RowSource = strSource

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a set of parenthesis:

```
strSource = "SELECT [ID], [VP_veiklioji], [VP_invented_Name], [Pareisk_pav], [Par_gavimo_data], [Statusas] " _
    & "FROM qryNewSys_srch " _
    & "WHERE ([ID] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
    & "Or [VP_veiklioji] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
    & "Or [VP_invented_Name] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
    & "Or [Pareisk_pav] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
    & "Or [Par_gavimo_data] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*') " _
    & "And [Statusas] = 'Ongoing' " _ 
    & "ORDER BY [ID] DESC"
```